# my computer wont turn on after installing new ram

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, hardware-failure

I've installed new RAM (Adata Premier PC3-10600 4GB DDR3 1333MHz 240Pin U-DIMM Ram) in my PC.

When I power it up, it turns on for two seconds and then shuts down, only to turn itself back on a second later. It works normally with the old RAM.

I've tried removing CMOS battery for a minute, but it didn't work.

I checked motherboard model and RAM compatibility before installing and it was OK.

The motherboard model is: [MSI P41-C33 (MS-7610)](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P41-C33.html)

Comment: Does the motherboard do any beeps often they do if there is an issue then you can look up the beep code to find the issue

Comment: No there is no beep or any other sound

Comment: Is it ECC RAM? some desktop units can't run ECC.

Comment: How can i know if is it ECC or not?

Answer (score 2):

You've either got a defective RAM module, or you're getting a bad connection in the RAM slot.  The only sensible way to test would be to install your RAM in another motherboard compatible with that exact module type, or conversely try a known good, identical module ("known good" by way of being pulled from a working computer) in your motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Your MB has two RAM slots. So things to try:

- install only new RAM

  - rise voltage of RAM if BIOS has such option
- switch slots of new and old RAM

Comment: I tried but nothing happened. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: BIOS update (if not a recent version), PSU check (not likely to be a problem, but...). How exactly did You check compatibility of Your new DDR and MB? What the old module is?